# Google Sheets: Bold part of a custom formula?

Tags: google-sheets

i have the following code:

```
="Health:"&char(10)&Info!D2
```

I want the "Health:" part to be Bold and Underlined and the Info it's pulling to be regular.
Similar to this:

**Health:**

38

.

But they are in a merged cell

See: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQMcUolEtiO_cwbg7BSLMUrGMcYN3srKnqSPDkUAkJpqntZ6giMx--uc-Mogqfmt0PZoPkXjXjnfsyF/pubhtml?gid=22908179&single=true

I want it to look similar to Size/Weight/etc... but i want them to be in a merged cell.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, at this time it's impossible to partially format anything that is a result of a formula.

There is a question (and answer) on Stack Exchange about this:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/87710/google-spreadsheet-partial-formatting-using-formula-in-cell

Answer stated:

*Partial formatting of cell content is a recent addition to Google Sheets, and it not really integrated with the rest of spreadsheet logic. The only thing you can format in this way is a string entered directly into a cell, as some text here. Using any kind of formula, even the simplest ="some text here", is incompatible with partial formatting.*

Comment: Related (same answer but newer and with sources): https://stackoverflow.com/q/49287090/9337071