# How to add empty cells and change color of substring in cell?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I add an empty cell using Google Apps Script? Lets say I find a given value in a cell and I wan't to add an empty cell below or above it.

Also, how can I change the color of a substring inside a cell? Lets say my string is: TTP'112'223 , and I want the bold number in red: TTP'**112**'223

So far I haven't found any example on how to do this, thats why I don't have any initial code.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:

For changing text style of a substring this example helped me:

```
// Sets all cells in range B2:D4 to have the text "Hello world", with 
"Hello" bolded.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");
var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle()
    .setBold(true)
    .build();
var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText("Hello world")
    .setTextStyle(0, 5, bold)
    .build();
 range.setRichTextValue(richText);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setrichtextvaluevalue

Comment: Try [insertCells(shiftDimension)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#insertCells(Dimension))

Comment: As for the font color take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49289754/7215091

Comment: You could have found this yourself by Googling `changing font color of a substring in cell of a spreadsheet with google apps script`

Comment: @Cooper doing that did not answer my questions. But a possible solution and added it above.

Comment: @Cooper as for the insertCells function I get the following error: `TypeError: range.insertCells is not a function`